# bash error when starting shell from tmux

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, shell, tmux

When I open a new shell in `tmux` I get an error message. This error message does not show up when I start a new shell in `GNOME terminal`.

#### What might `tmux` be running at startup that I need to check?

This isn't coming from `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_aliases` (I guess obviously since it doesn't happen except in `tmux`. But I checked anyway.)

---

Here is the error:

```
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try `cut --help' for more information.
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
cut: the delimiter must be a single character
Try `cut --help' for more information.
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
```

Comment: Have you checked `~/.bash_profile`?

Comment: @tonchis It checks for bash, if ∃ then `sh $HOME/.bashrc`, else set `PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`.

Comment: Could you please be more precise about the contents of  `.bash_profile`?

Comment: @KarstenS. https://dpaste.de/ky8K

Answer (score 1):

This can have several reasons:

You might have an alias for `tmux` which sets special command line options

*or*

`tmux` on some machines does not start a login shell. You could check [Why ~/.bash_profile is not getting sourced when opening a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121073/why-bash-profile-is-not-getting-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal) to figure out more.

*or*

You might have a code block like the following in one of your bash files:

```
if [[ -n "$TMUX" ]]; then
    does something that causes the error
fi
```

which will only be executed when run under tmux.

*or*

Your `.tmux.conf` might have an error or it contains statements of the form

```
source-file "/path/to/some.conf"
run-script "/path/to/script"
```

where one of the given files contains the error. You could try running the script standalone and see if you get the same error.

To test what gets loaded you can add a line like

```
echo ".bash_profile"
```

to your `.bash_profile` and a corresponding line to any other file that `bash` or `sh` might load (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, `.bash_login`). Then see which of those files is loaded in a normal terminal session and which is loaded when `tmux` is started.

You could also try to type `logout` to se whether it is a login shell or not: If the process ends, it was a login shell. Otherwise it will tell you that it isn't. However I'm currently not sure how `tmux` will behave if it is not a login shell.

Additionally, if you ever played around with system files, you might also want to check

- `/etc/profile`
- `/usr/local/etc/tmux.conf`

What does also get loaded is `~/.inputrc`, but that's not executed like a script.

Look it all up with `man bash` and `man tmux` in section `FILES`.

Comment: Thanks Karsten. My `~/.tmux.conf` does not have the words `source` or `script` in it.

Comment: `logout` does close a tmux shell.

Comment: I don't have a `/usr/local/etc/tmux.conf` and `/etc/profile` is here: http://sprunge.us/McIT?bash

Comment: @isomorphismes Would you mind pasting `~/.tmux.conf` as well? Maybe there are more possibilities. Do you have one of the other files mentioned in my answer in your home directory? If yes, please post also, but always check if it contains private information that's not for the public!

Comment: Any scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`?

Comment: Ooh, yeah! Now we're getting somewhere. I have 3, `rvm.sh`, bash completion, and nodejs. `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh` calls `/etc/bash_completion`, which looks like this: http://sprunge.us/gOFJ?bash and *does* reference `cut`. Woo!

Comment: `~/.tmux.conf` looks like this: http://sprunge.us/QZDN

Comment: `bash_completion` is interesting, but should be loaded not only for tmux. First try adding `set-option -g default-shell /bin/bash` somewhere at the top of `~/.tmux.conf` and see if it changes somehow. Next is: try moving all files from `/etc/profile.d/` somewhere else. If the problem is gone, add one after the other and check again -- one by one, so you can find out which file might cause the problem.